# Google Cloud Speech API Not working in browser

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-speech-api, google-client, google-auth-library

I am using Google cloud speech-to-text API and setup project in localhost and live with credential and environment variable. **It working with only command line while I run it through browser it gives me below error**

> Fatal error: Uncaught DomainException: Could not load the default
>   credentials. Browse to
>   https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials
>   for more information in
>   /jet/app/www/default/speech/vendor/google/auth/src/ApplicationDefaultCredentials.php:156
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /jet/app/www/default/speech/vendor/google/gax/src/CredentialsWrapper.php(197):
>   Google\Auth\ApplicationDefaultCredentials::getCredentials(Array,
>   Object(Google\Auth\HttpHandler\Guzzle6HttpHandler), NULL, NULL) #1
>   /jet/app/www/default/speech/vendor/google/gax/src/CredentialsWrapper.php(114):
>   Google\ApiCore\CredentialsWrapper::buildApplicationDefaultCredentials(Array,
>   Object(Google\Auth\HttpHandler\Guzzle6HttpHandler)) #2
>   /jet/app/www/default/speech/vendor/google/gax/src/GapicClientTrait.php(326):
>   Google\ApiCore\CredentialsWrapper::build(Array) #3
>   /jet/app/www/default/speech/vendor/google/gax/src/GapicClientTrait.php(308):
>   Google\Cloud\Speech\V1\Gapic\SpeechGapicClient->createCredentialsWrapper(NULL,
>   Array) #4 /jet/app/www/default/speech in
>   /jet/app/www/default/speech/vendor/google/gax/src/CredentialsWrapper.php
>   on line 200

I am using Below Google Speech code:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples

https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/streaming-recognize

```
namespace Google\Cloud\Samples\Speech;

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Symfony\Component\Console\Application;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputDefinition;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

$inputDefinition = new InputDefinition([
    new InputArgument('audio-file', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'The audio file to transcribe'),
    new InputOption('model', null, InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED, 'The model to use'),
    new InputOption('encoding', null, InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED,
        'The encoding of the audio file. This is required if the encoding is ' .
        'unable to be determined. '
    )
]);

$application = new Application('Cloud Speech');
$application->add(new Command('transcribe'))
    ->setDefinition($inputDefinition)
    ->setDescription('Transcribe an audio file using Google Cloud Speech API')
    ->setHelp(<<<EOF
The <info>%command.name%</info> command transcribes audio from a file using the
Google Cloud Speech API.

<info>php %command.full_name% audio_file.wav</info>

EOF
    )
    ->setCode(function (InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output) {
        $audioFile = $input->getArgument('audio-file');
        transcribe_sync($audioFile);
    });

$application->add(new Command('transcribe-gcs'))
    ->setDefinition($inputDefinition)
    ->setDescription('Transcribe audio from a Storage Object using Google Cloud Speech API')
    ->setHelp(<<<EOF
The <info>%command.name%</info> command transcribes audio from a Cloud Storage
Object using the Google Cloud Speech API.

<info>php %command.full_name% gs://my-bucket/audio_file.wav</info>

EOF
    )
    ->setCode(function (InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output) {
        $audioFile = $input->getArgument('audio-file');
        if (!preg_match('/^gs:\/\/([a-z0-9\._\-]+)\/(\S+)$/', $audioFile, $matches)) {
            throw new \Exception('Invalid file name. Must be gs://[bucket]/[audiofile]');
        }
        transcribe_sync_gcs($audioFile);
    });

$application->add(new Command('transcribe-model'))
    ->setDefinition($inputDefinition)
    ->setDescription('Transcribe an audio file, with selected model, using Google Cloud Speech API')
    ->setHelp(<<<EOF
The <info>%command.name%</info> command transcribes audio from a file, with the 
selected model, using the Google Cloud Speech API.

<info>php %command.full_name% audio_file.wav model_name</info>

EOF
    )
    ->setCode(function (InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output) {
        $audioFile = $input->getArgument('audio-file');
        $modelName = $input->getOption('model');
        transcribe_model_selection($audioFile, $modelName);
    });

$application->add(new Command('transcribe-enhanced'))
    ->setDefinition($inputDefinition)
    ->setDescription('Transcribe an audio file, with an enhanced model, using Google Cloud Speech API')
    ->setHelp(<<<EOF
The <info>%command.name%</info> command transcribes audio from a file, with an enhanced 
model, using the Google Cloud Speech API.

<info>php %command.full_name% audio_file.wav model_name</info>

EOF
    )
    ->setCode(function (InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output) {
        $path = $input->getArgument('audio-file');
        transcribe_enhanced_model($path);
    });

$application->add(new Command('transcribe-punctuation'))
    ->setDefinition($inputDefinition)
    ->setDescription('Transcribe an audio file, with proper punctuation, using Google Cloud Speech API')
    ->setHelp(<<<EOF
The <info>%command.name%</info> command transcribes audio from a file, with 
proper punctuation, using the Google Cloud Speech API.

<info>php %command.full_name% audio_file.wav</info>

EOF
    )
    ->setCode(function (InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output) {
        $path = $input->getArgument('audio-file');
        transcribe_auto_punctuation($path);
    });

$application->add(new Command('transcribe-async'))
    ->setDefinition($inputDefinition)
    ->setDescription('Transcribe an audio file asynchronously using Google Cloud Speech API')
    ->setHelp(<<<EOF
The <info>%command.name%</info> command transcribes audio from a file using the
Google Cloud Speech API asynchronously.

<info>php %command.full_name% audio_file.wav</info>

EOF
    )
    ->setCode(function (InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output) {
        $audioFile = $input->getArgument('audio-file');
        transcribe_async($audioFile);
    });

$application->add(new Command('transcribe-async-gcs'))
    ->setDefinition($inputDefinition)
    ->setDescription('Transcribe audio asynchronously from a Storage Object using Google Cloud Speech API')
    ->setHelp(<<<EOF
The <info>%command.name%</info> command transcribes audio from a Cloud Storage
object asynchronously using the Google Cloud Speech API.

<info>php %command.full_name% gs://my-bucket/audio_file.wav</info>

EOF
    )
    ->setCode(function (InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output) {
        $audioFile = $input->getArgument('audio-file');
        if (!preg_match('/^gs:\/\/([a-z0-9\._\-]+)\/(\S+)$/', $audioFile, $matches)) {
            throw new \Exception('Invalid file name. Must be gs://[bucket]/[audiofile]');
        }
        transcribe_async_gcs($audioFile);
    });

$application->add(new Command('transcribe-async-words'))
    ->setDefinition($inputDefinition)
    ->setDescription('Transcribe an audio file asynchronously and print word time offsets using Google Cloud Speech API')
    ->setHelp(<<<EOF
The <info>%command.name%</info> command transcribes audio from a file using the
Google Cloud Speech API asynchronously and prints word time offsets.

<info>php %command.full_name% audio_file.wav</info>

EOF
    )
    ->setCode(function (InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output) {
        $audioFile = $input->getArgument('audio-file');
        transcribe_async_words($audioFile);
    });

$application->add(new Command('transcribe-stream'))
    ->setDefinition($inputDefinition)
    ->setDescription('Transcribe a stream of audio using Google Cloud Speech API')
    ->setHelp(<<<EOF
The <info>%command.name%</info> command transcribes audio from a stream using
the Google Cloud Speech API.

<info>php %command.full_name% audio_file.wav</info>

EOF
    )
    ->setCode(function (InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output) {
        streaming_recognize(
            $input->getArgument('audio-file')
        );
    });

// for testing
if (getenv('PHPUNIT_TESTS') === '1') {
    return $application;
}

$application->run();
```

Comment: You need to secify env variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS for service account key, see the link in the warning

Comment: I have already did that And its working fine in command line while i run file through coomand line "php speech.php" it will working and executing result as expected but while same file run into browser it gives me above error

Comment: Try to var_dump(getenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS')); in browser. Next - try to chown www-data:www-data to key file.

Answer (score 3):

put it to manual

```
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/service-account-credentials.json');
```